# Submit a query automatically with cheerio (like JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

I have to do the following: given a page loaded from a server, I have to submit a form in that page automatically after loading it, filling up all of its input fields with the same string (`test worked`). This is obviously a simplification of my problem, but it's close enough!

At the moment I am getting the form, and using https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio to explore it:

```
var URL = http://www.example.com/form/index.html"
// ...load the page ...
$ = cheerio.load( fetchedPageText );
```

At the moment, I have the following code:

```
var $ = cheerio.load( fetchedPageText );

var forms = $('form');
for( var i1 = 0, l1 = forms.length; i1 < l1; i1 ++ ){
  var form = forms[ i1 ];

  inputFields = $( 'input', form );


  console.log("******FORM ACTION: ", form.attribs.action );
  console.log("******FORM: ", form );

  for( var i2 = 0, l2 = inputFields.length; i2 < l2; i2 ++ ){
    var inputField = inputFields[ i2 ];

    console.log( inputField );
    console.log("**************INPUT FIELD ", inputField );


    /* At this point, I have `action` and every input field */


  }
};
```

Questions:

- At the moment, `submit` is relative to the page I have downloaded. How do I make sure that I submit things in the right spot? Should I do url.parse and work out the gull path for the action from the URL?
- How do you actually create a "post" string? Or, even better, how would you post this form?
- I realise that this might not work (the form might have Javascript, etc.). However, is there anything else I need to be careful about, when submitting this form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To post the form to the correct address you must combine page's base url and the one in the post attribute. [url.resolve(from, to)](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_resolve_from_to) can help

To post the form you can use e.g. http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/ or some other ajax library with support for [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

You should be aware that many sites apply various anti-spam measures and they will reject your requests if not properly formed. It must be checked on per-site basis.

You should also be aware that mass mailing or mass form submitting is in some countries prosecuted by law.

You should be aware that **there are usually much easier APIs** to be used by 3rd parties (other then parsing html forms) based on JSON and REST or SOAP.

If you need to submit pages to a web server legally better option would be to negotiate another API with the server owner. It should not be a problem even with government servers as many of them are opening due to the [Open Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_data) initiative (America, Europe, India, ..)

Comment: No worries about spamming issue, I am not a spammer. The API cannot be changed, but that's OK. Thanks for the superAgent link, much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for rising my reputation score, much appreciated!